# Force ExpanderView to expand while in the XAML Designer

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, design-time-data

Is there a way to force the XAML designer to expand and show the contents of an ExpanderView?
I have tried setting the `IsExpanded` property to `true` as well as binding it to one of my Design ViewModels that sets it as `true` and neither method worked.